# Marker Clusterer, not zooming in when clicked

Tags: google-maps, markerclusterer

I'm using Marker Clusterer with all the default settings, on a map also using just default settings. The marker clusters display fine, but unlike the example in the documentation, the map does not zoom in when a cluster is clicked. The map only centers on the click on cluster but does not zoom!

Has anyone else had this problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That setting was true thank you davidhund. I replaced the code with a different version, and the problem has vanished.

Answer (score 0):

Dreendle: the default `zoomOnClick` setting is `true` so that clicking a Cluster should zoom in. Are you sure you have not set `zoomOnClick` to false?

There are no script errors?